# How to avoid dictionary override reference value of object when apply Dictionary.Clear()

Tags: c#, dictionary, asp.net-core-6.0

I am working on .NET CORE 6. I have nested `Dictionary<int, string>` where I am adding value in loop to nested dictionary from string. The string holds multiple record where each record holds 15 columns hence dictionary is useful to hold keys.

After 15 iteration, I add nested/ child dictionary to parent `Dictionary<string, string>` and then I set nested dictionary to start again from counter 0. The issue is once I clear nested dictionary using `Clear()`, it also clear data from Parent dictionary. I need help on this and how I can approach to avoid that, `dataItemDictionary.Clear();`

```
 private Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, string>> ConvertStream(string stream)
    {
        Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, string>> dataDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, string>>();

        Dictionary<int, string> dataItemDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stream))
        {
            string column = string.Empty;
            int dataItemDictionaryindex = 0;
            int dataDictionaryIndex = 0;
            int columnCounter = 16;

            foreach(char c in stream)
            {
                if(c.Equals('|'))
                {
                    dataItemDictionary.Add(dataItemDictionaryindex, column);

                    column = string.Empty;

                    dataItemDictionaryindex++;
                     
                    if (columnCounter == dataItemDictionaryindex)
                    {
                        Dictionary<int, string> data = new Dictionary<int, string>();

                        data = dataItemDictionary; // need help here...

                        dataDictionary.Add("Record@" + dataDictionaryIndex, data);

                        dataItemDictionary.Clear();

                        dataDictionaryIndex++;
                        columnCounter = columnCounter * (dataDictionaryIndex + 1);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!c.Equals('\r') && !c.Equals('\n'))
                    {
                        column = column + c;
                    }              
                }
            }
        }
        return dataDictionary;
    }
```

Comment: What is format of your data and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I read stream from file and is in string. Then in above code I am trying to separate column based on vertical bar followed by add all the records to dictionary

Comment: Can you please show example of the string?

Comment: what is key in `dataDictionary`? Should it be number of column or number of row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is a [reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types). Use the [copy constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-collections-generic-dictionary-2-ctor(system-collections-generic-idictionary((-0-1)))) of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` to create a new collection instance.

```
Dictionary<int, string> data = new Dictionary<int, string>(dataItemDictionary);
```